# How to extract and convert data from JSON?

Tags: javascript, json, api

I am currently working on a project that uses the CitySDK module which taps into the U.S. Census bureau API. I can pull data from the API and that aspect works fine. I actually get back data that looks like this:

```
{
  "level": "county",
  "zip": "30519",
  "variables": [
    "income",
    "poverty"
  ],
  "api": "acs5",
  "year": "2013",
  "tract": "050606",
  "sublevel": false,
  "lat": "+34.0879823",
  "lng": "-083.9411706",
  "state": "13",
  "county": "135",
  "blockGroup": "3",
  "place": null,
  "place_name": null,
  "data": [
    {
      "income": "60445",
      "poverty": "113986"
    }
  ]
}
```

It is almost what I want! The problem that I have is that I want to show only two pieces of data: [ { "income": "60445", "poverty": "113986" } ] } more specifically, I would want only the "60445" and "113986" returned. I know that they would be returned as strings so I would also need them converted over to numbers.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Here is my code:

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
   <title>Test File</title>
</head>
<body>

<input type="number" id="zip" placeholder="Zip"></input>
<input type="number" id="year" placeholder="Year"></input>
<input type="text" id="variables" placeholder="variables"></input>
<!--<input type="number" id="tract" placeholder="tract"></input>-->
<button onclick="data()">Submit</button>
<ul>
  <li>population</li>
  <li>poverty</li>
  <li>median_male_age</li>
  <li>median_home_value</li>
</ul>

<p>Please note: The data may take 3-5 seconds to appear.</p>

<p id="data">Data Here:</p>

<script src="js/api.js"></script>
```

JavaScript:

```
var sdk = new CitySDK(); //Create the CitySDK Instance
var census = sdk.modules.census; //Create an instance of the module
census.enable("HIDDEN"); //Enable module        
with the API key


//creating the request variable. Please note that I have left in income as        
the default variable.
var request = {
  "level": "county",
  "zip": "",
  "variables": [
    "income"
 ],
  "api": "acs5",
  "year": "",
   "tract": ""
 };

 //Function which will gather data from user and then submit it to the API.     
//The API will then return 
//the data that was requested. 
function data(){
   var zip = document.getElementById("zip").value;
   var year = document.getElementById("year").value;
   var variable = document.getElementById("variables").value;
   //var tract = document.getElementById("tract").value;
   request.zip = zip;
   request.year = year;
   request.variables.push(variable);

   //The request to gather the actual data.
   census.APIRequest(request, function (response) {
    
    //Outputs the raw JSON text
    jQuery("#data").text(JSON.stringify(response, null, 4));

     //THE BELOW TWO LINES ARE WHERE I HAVE EXPERIMENTED 
    //jQuery("#data").text(JSON.stringify(response.variables[0], null, 4));
    //console.log(JSON.parse(test));
   });     
  }
```

Using `JSON.stringify(response.variables[0]` gets close to the desired output. In this case, I will output income. If `response.variables[1]` were used it would output poverty or the variable the user had entered. However, I do not want to see income or poverty but the values, from the API turned to number format.

Comment: When you get the response back, it's already a JavaScript object structure. Stringifying it makes things much much harder.  Just access `response.data[0].income` and `response.data[0].poverty`.

Comment: Okay, response.data[0].income works! Just working on converting the value over to a number and not a string! Thank you!

Comment: To make them numbers, just prefix with `+` - `+response.data[0].income`

Comment: Yes! That works, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointy mentioned, the response is already in JSON format(maybe).

If it is something like response.data[0].income could work.

If you want to fiddle with it, set a `debugger` in the code and open the console.

Or its possible it is not in JSON format but the server is sending it back as a big string, in which case you will want to do something like `JSON.parse(response)` to put it in JSON format.

To Convert strings to numbers you can use something like parseInt or parseFloat.

```
> parseInt("113986")
< 113986

> parseFloat("113986.3939393")
< 113986.3939393
```